# How to redirect WooCommerce shop to a custom shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website built on the Ample Business theme with the Woocommerce plugin installed and activated. We have created a custom shop page and want to redirect the Woocommerce /shop/ URL to the new page. I have read several posts that prescribe answers, but none seem to work. The page will not redirect.

What I've tried:

Added the following code to the child theme's functions.php file:

```
    // Redirect WooCommerce Shop URL 
    function wpc_shop_url_redirect() 
    { if( is_shop() ){ 
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/shop2/' ) ); // Assign custom internal page here exit(); } } 
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpc_shop_url_redirect' );
```

Tried a standard 301 redirect via .htaccess.

These solutions do not work and I can not simply create a new template file for archive_product.php because all Woocommerce files reside in the plugins folder as opposed to the theme folder. I do not want the file overwritten with each update.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `shop2` page. then create [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) then assign WordPress page template to page `shop2` page.

Below is the example template file look like. you can give this file name like `template-shop2.php`

```
<?php 

    /* Template Name: Example Template */ 

    get_header();

    // your product display code.

    get_footer();

?>
```

Then you can use your `template_redirect` and redirect to your `shop2`. this code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function custom_shop_page_redirect() {
    if( is_shop() ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/shop2/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_shop_page_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that I inadvertently had the parent theme activated and was editing the child theme's functions.php file. The following code added to functions.php successfully redirects the shop page:

```
// Redirect WooCommerce Shop URL
function wpc_shop_url_redirect() {
    if( is_shop() ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/store/' ) ); // Assign custom internal page here
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpc_shop_url_redirect' );
```

Comment: Kudos to https://wpcodeus.com/how-to-redirect-woocommerce-shop-url/.

Comment: And you Bhautik! your solution appears to work as well.